# cURL to follow redirects and get all URLs

Tags: curl

I wrote a simple bash script who takes a list of URLs and outputs a CSV with some data for each one : url, status code and target url :

```bsh
while read url
do
    urlstatus=$(curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --head --insecure --write-out '%{http_code} , %{redirect_url}' "$url" -I )
    echo "$url , $urlstatus" >> "$1-out.csv"
done < $1
```

Sometimes an URL have 2 or 3 redirects, I'd like to get them all and print them in the output file.

I've found the `-L` option and the `%{url_effective}` filter to the last URLs :

```bsh
    urlstatus2=$(curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --head --insecure --write-out ' , %{url_effective}' "$url" -L -I )
```

But I'd like to have all URLs from the origin to the final one and add them to the csv.

Comment: Do you have an example of a page with more than one redirects so we can test?

Comment: Yes of course : https://aep-beta.onpc.fr/lycees/dom/region/DOM/ECOL 
301 -> 301 -> 200

Comment: if you make it http, it has even 3 redirections 302 -> 301 -> 301 -> 200 :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a recursive function:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
get_redirects(){
    i=${2:-1}
    read status url <<< $(curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --head --insecure --write-out '%{http_code}\t%{redirect_url}\n' "$1" -I)
    printf '%d: %s --> %s\n' "$i" "$1" "$status";
    if [ "$1" = "$url" ] || [ $i -gt 9 ]; then
        echo "Recursion detected or more redirections than allowed. Stop."
    else
      case $status in
          30*) get_redirects "$url" "$((i+1))"
               ;;
      esac
    fi
}
```

Usage:

```bsh
$ get_redirects https://aep-beta.onpc.fr/lycees/dom/region/DOM/ECOL
https://aep-beta.onpc.fr/lycees/dom/region/DOM/ECOL --> 301
https://aep-beta.onpc.fr/onglet/lycee/dom --> 301
https://aep-beta.onpc.fr/onglet/lycee/outre-mer --> 200
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to tell that some times I deal with infinite redirections (due to errors in redirection rules) ! This case will crash the recursive function I think !

Comment: What does curl do in this case? You could add a counter and quit after n redirects. Or quit directly if "$1==$url" (or simply hit ctrl+c if interactive)....

Comment: added a counter to stop after 10th request.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@pLumo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/236063/plumo)'s answer, this function removes the recursiveness and allows custom arguments to be supplied to curl

```
#!/bin/bash
get_redirects(){
  url=$1
  declare -a params=("${@:2}")

  for i in {1..100}; do
    read status url <<< $(curl "$url" -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -o /dev/null --silent --write-out '%{http_code}\t%{redirect_url}\n' "${params[@]}");
    printf '%d: %s --> %s\n' "$i" "$url" "$status";
    if (( status < 300 || status >= 400 )); then break; fi
  done
}
```

Usage:

```
get_redirects http://example.com/endpoint -X POST -H "Authentication: Bearer ..." -d "param=value"
```